# RegEx filename Exclusion match

Tags: regex

I've seen other posts on SO for RegEx matches excluding strings (using negative look ahead / look behind) but i'm still having a hard time getting it to work. Was hoping someone could help.

I have a RegEx

```
\.(gif|jpg|png)$
```

Which i use to match any filenames ending in (gif/jpg/png)

However i want to use an exclusion list so that certain file names will not be matched.

eg

- match any http://example.com/images/filename.jpg / gif / png
- except (http://example.com/images/foo.jpg, http://example.com/images/foo.gif, http://example.com/images/foo.png) (http://example.com/images/bar.jpg, http://example.com/images/bar.gif, http://example.com/images/bar.png)

Thanks very much!

Comment: To echo @MarkRoberts - why does this have to be done as a regex?

Comment: The program i'm working with takes its input has a RegEx string for file matching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the number of exclusions is low, you can use multiple negative look-behinds like this:

```
(?<!\/foo)(?<!\/bar)(?<!www\.site\.com\/foobar)\.(gif|jpg|png)$
```

The '/' before foo and bar makes sure the full name matches foo or bar, it doesn't only end in it. If it is possible that there is no '/' before the filename, you need to adjust this part.

One drawback of look-behinds is that you can only use a defined length, so no `*`, `+` or `{1,5}`is allowed. You have to specify every exception by itself.

Note that look-arounds don't change the 'position' in the string from which it is looked at, which is why you can concatenate them like that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
^(?!(foo|bar)\.(gif|jpg|png)$).*\.(gif|jpg|png)$
```

[See it](http://www.rubular.com/r/9OZvpmtUpP)

Comment: Appologies, just realised i need a URL as part of the match which your answer did not work with.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that trying to read my code 6 weeks later means it's almost always better to apply filters like that separately from the regular expression.  If you'll pardon a little perl:

```
# Apply original png/gif/jpg filter to get list of files
my @files = qw/
    asdf.jpg
    bar.png
    fdsa.png
    foo.gif
    foo.jpg
/;

# Filter files to only those that don't look like ^<forbidden>\.
@files = grep {
    $_ !~ /^(foo|bar)\./
} @files;
```

This is notably also how people tend to string shell commands together.